# Firebase Database not respond in Simulator and Real Device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to work with `Firebase` `Real Time Database` and set the all instructions. But database not respond the any `setValue` functions. Not trigger any prop and not printing snapshot's in the path.

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function I set my configuration as

```
 FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Then in my controller, I have 2 lines of code about database.

```
let rootReference = Database.database().reference()
rootReference.child("users").childByAutoId().setValue("asdfas", forKey: "asdfasd")
```

I imported the FirebaseDatabase and in the Real-Time-Database section I set my security rules as

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

There is no change even I set the setting value by a `UIButton` item.

I check it out my `App Transport Security` & `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and its already correct, they matches in bundle ID's and etc.

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with adding `FirebaseCore` library to project.

`FirebaseDatabase` aka `RealTimeDatabase & FireStore` cannot respond if you not add the pod `Firebase/Core`. Do not forget to add the any core functionality of the firebase libraries.